# Menu items move on hover and not able to center

Tags: html, css, menu

I am working on the main horizontal navigation for this site: http://www.myfortune3cart.com/journeyfilm/

I have two problems that I have tried to solve and can't find anywhere in the CSS.

1. I can't center the menu items in the menu container. I have tried to use text-align:center; and margin:0 auto; in various divs to no avail.
2. When hovering over the items they move. The Buy link (with a drop-down moves differently that the others). I have tried setting the padding and looking for transitions but can't solve the problem.

I would put the code here but I am not even sure what part of the css is affecting these two items. I am sure it is something stupid that I am overlooking but I am tired of pulling my hair out over this.

Any help would be appreciated. I am trying to get it to look like this: http://www.studiobenna.com/jf/

Thank you,

Matt

Comment: You should put the code for your menu on [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) and add a link in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for your 1st problem

```
.wrapper_menu {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 586px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

You need to give some width to .wrapper_menu

For the 2nd problem, remove extra padding from

```
.menu li.nodrop:hover {
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0.25em 1.563em;
}

.menu li:hover {
    border-bottom: medium none;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 0.25em 1.563em;
}
```

Remove padding from both also give proper height to `.wrapper_menu .menu`

Answer (score 0):

update f3menu.css with this one

```
.wrapper_menu {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.wrapper_menu .menu {
    height: 43px;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}
.wrapper_menu_full {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.menu_header_bg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper_menu_full .menu {
    height: 43px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.wrapper_menu_full .menu_whole_width {
    height: 43px;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu li {
    border: medium none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu .fullwidth {
    position: static !important;
}
.menu li:hover {
    border-bottom: medium none;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu li.nodrop:hover {
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu li.nodrop:hover a {
    padding: 0.25em 1.563em;
}
.menu li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    font-family: "ITCAvantGardeGothicStdBook";
    font-size: 14px;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 8px 25px 7px !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu li:hover a {
    padding: 0.25em 1.563em;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: none;
    z-index: 11;
}
.menu li:hover div a {
    display: inline;
}
.menu li .drop, .menu li:hover .drop {
    padding: 0.25em 1.563em;
}
.menu li.right {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.menu li.right:hover {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.menu .dropdown_1column, .menu .dropdown_2columns, .menu .dropdown_3columns, .menu .dropdown_4columns, .menu .dropdown_5columns, .menu .dropdown_fullwidth {
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px;
    left: -999em;
    margin: 4px auto;
    padding: 10px 3px 10px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
}
.menu .dropdown_1column {
}
.menu .dropdown_2columns {
    width: 375px;
}
.menu .dropdown_3columns {
    width: 455px;
}
.menu .dropdown_4columns {
    width: 610px;
}
.menu .dropdown_5columns {
    width: 765px;
}
.menu .dropdown_fullwidth {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 920px;
}
.menu li .first_fullwidth {
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px;
}
.menu li:hover .dropdown_1column, .menu li:hover .dropdown_2columns, .menu li:hover .dropdown_3columns, .menu li:hover .dropdown_4columns, .menu li:hover .dropdown_5columns {
    left: -1px;
    top: 35px;
}
.menu li:hover .dropdown_fullwidth {
    display: block;
    left: 21px;
    top: 33px;
}
.wrapper_menu_full .menu li:hover .dropdown_fullwidth {
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -470px;
    top: 32px;
}
.menu li .align_right {
    border-radius: 5px 0 5px 5px;
}
.menu li:hover .align_right {
    left: auto;
    right: -1px;
    top: 25px;
}
.menu li.right:hover .dropdown_fullwidth {
    right: 18px;
    top: 33px;
}
.wrapper_menu_full .menu li.right:hover .dropdown_fullwidth {
    left: auto;
    margin-right: -471px;
    right: 50%;
    top: 32px;
}
.menu .col_1, .menu .col_2, .menu .col_3, .menu .col_4, .menu .col_5, .menu .col_6 {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.menu .col_1 {
    min-width: 145px;
}
.menu .col_2 {
    width: 375px;
}
.menu .col_3 {
    width: 455px;
}
.menu .col_4 {
    width: 610px;
}
.menu .col_5 {
    width: 765px;
}
.menu .col_6 {
    width: 920px;
}
.menu .firstcolumn {
    clear: left;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.menu p, .menu ul, .menu li, .menu h2, .menu h3 {
    font-family: "ITCAvantGardeGothicStdBook";
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: left;
}
.menu p {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000;
}
.menu .strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.menu .italic {
    font-style: italic;
}
.menu h2, .menu h3 {
    margin-top: 7px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000;
}
.menu h2 {
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
}
.menu h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}
.menu li:hover div a {
    border: medium none;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
}
.menu .pusher {
    margin-top: 18px;
}
.menu .help, .menu .favorite, .menu .mail, .menu .print {
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    padding-left: 36px;
}
.menu .help {
    background: url("help.png") no-repeat scroll 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.menu .favorite {
    background: url("favorite.png") no-repeat scroll 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.menu .mail {
    background: url("mail.png") no-repeat scroll 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.menu .print {
    background: url("print.png") no-repeat scroll 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.menu .imgshadow_dark, .menu .imgshadow_light {
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 4px;
}
.menu .img_left {
    float: left;
    margin: 2px 15px 5px 0;
    width: auto;
}
.menu .img_right {
    float: right;
    margin: 2px 0 5px 15px;
    width: auto;
}
.menu li .black_box, .menu li .dark_grey_box {
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #eeeeee;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
.menu li ul {
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0 0 12px;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu li ul li {
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
    width: 145px;
}
.menu li ul li a {
    padding: 0;
}
.menu li ul li:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: medium none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu li .greybox li {
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 0 4px;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    width: 131px;
}
.menu li .greybox li:hover {
    margin: 0 0 4px;
    padding: 4px 6px;
}
.menu li .plus li {
    margin: 0 0 4px;
    padding: 0 0 0 21px;
    width: 165px;
}
.menu li .plus li:hover {
    margin: 0 0 4px;
    padding: 0 0 0 21px;
}
.menu li ul.social {
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu li ul.social li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 12px 12px 0;
    padding-top: 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 32px;
}
.menu li ul.social li img {
    border: medium none;
}
.menu li ul.social li:hover {
    margin: -1px 12px 12px 0;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.menu li ul.social li span {
    display: none;
}
.menu .levels, .menu .levels ul {
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu li:hover .levels a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu .levels a {
    display: block;
    padding-right: 5px !important;
    width: 10em;
}
.menu .levels li {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu .levels li ul {
    border-radius: 5px;
    left: -999em;
    margin: 15px 0 0 4px;
    padding: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -22px;
}
.menu .levels li:hover ul ul, .menu .levels li:hover ul ul ul {
    left: -999em;
}
.menu .levels li:hover ul, .menu .levels li li:hover ul, .menu .levels li li li:hover ul {
    left: 99%;
}
.contact_form label, .contact_form legend {
    font-family: "ITCAvantGardeGothicStdBook";
    font-size: 12px;
}
.contact_form legend {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.contact_form {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.contact_form label {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    width: 80px;
}
.contact_form input, .contact_form textarea, .contact_form select {
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: "ITCAvantGardeGothicStdBook";
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 7px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
}
.contact_form textarea {
    resize: none;
}
.contact_form .required {
    color: #c00;
}
.contact_form .form_buttons {
    margin: 4px 0 0 80px;
}
.contact_form input.button {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 4px 7px;
    width: 80px;
}
.contact_form .special {
    display: none;
}
.contact_form .error, .contact_form .sent {
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    text-shadow: none;
}
.contact_form .error {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fbe5e2;
    border: 1px solid #f2a197;
    color: #992213;
}
.contact_form .sent {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #e1f8cb;
    border: 1px solid #c6d880;
    color: #37620d;
}
.menu_light_theme ul li:hover, .menu_light_theme ul li.nodrop:hover {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #f4f4f4, #eeeeee) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid #444444;
}
.menu_light_theme ul li:hover a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    color: #161616;
}
.menu_light_theme ul li .drop, .menu_light_theme .menu li.noactive .drop {
    background: url("arrow_down1.png") no-repeat scroll right 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.menu_light_theme ul li:hover .drop {
    background: url("arrow_down1.png") no-repeat scroll right 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.menu_light_theme ul .dropdown_1column, .menu_light_theme ul .dropdown_2columns, .menu_light_theme ul .dropdown_3columns, .menu_light_theme ul .dropdown_4columns, .menu_light_theme ul .dropdown_5columns, .menu_light_theme ul .dropdown_fullwidth, .menu_light_theme ul .levels li ul {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #eeeeee, #bbbbbb) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid #444444;
}
.menu_light_theme ul p, .menu_light_theme ul h2, .menu_light_theme ul h3, .menu_light_theme ul li ul li {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff;
}
.menu_light_theme ul h2, .menu_light_theme ul h3 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #888888;
}
.menu_light_theme ul .imgshadow_dark {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;
}
.menu_light_theme ul .imgshadow_light {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #777777;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #666666;
}
.menu_light_theme ul li .black_box {
    background-color: #333333;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #000000 inset;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
}
.menu_light_theme ul li .dark_grey_box {
    background-color: #555555;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #111111 inset;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
}
.menu_light_theme ul li .greybox li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f4f4f4;
    border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
}
.menu_light_theme ul li .greybox li:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
.menu_light_theme ul li .plus li {
    background: url("plus.png") no-repeat scroll left 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.menu_light_theme ul .levels a.parent, .menu_light_theme ul .levels a.parent:hover {
    background: url("arrow_right1.png") no-repeat scroll right center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.menu_light_theme ul .contact_form input:focus, .menu_light_theme ul .contact_form textarea:focus, .menu_light_theme ul .contact_form select:focus, .menu_light_theme ul .contact_form input:hover, .menu_light_theme ul .contact_form textarea:hover, .menu_light_theme ul .contact_form select:hover {
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.menu_light_theme ul .contact_form input, .menu_light_theme ul textarea, .menu_light_theme ul select {
    background-color: #222222;
    border: 1px solid #0a0a0a;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.menu_light_theme ul .contact_form input.button {
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    border: 1px solid #0a0a0a;
    color: #cccccc;
}
.menu_light_theme ul .contact_form input.button:hover {
    background-color: #222222;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    color: #eeeeee;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu li:hover div a {
    border-bottom: medium none;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu li.noactive a {
    color: #eeeeee;
}
.menu_dark_theme ul li:hover, .menu_dark_theme ul li.nodrop:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 0 solid transparent;
}
.menu_dark_theme ul li:hover a {
    color: #ccc;
}
.menu_dark_theme ul li .drop, .menu_dark_theme .menu li.noactive .drop {
    background: url("arrow_down2.png") no-repeat scroll right center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.menu_dark_theme ul li:hover .drop {
    background: url("arrow_down2.png") no-repeat scroll right center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.menu_dark_theme ul .dropdown_1column, .menu_dark_theme ul .dropdown_2columns, .menu_dark_theme ul .dropdown_3columns, .menu_dark_theme ul .dropdown_4columns, .menu_dark_theme ul .dropdown_5columns, .menu_dark_theme ul .dropdown_fullwidth, .menu_dark_theme ul .levels li ul {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #161616, #0a0a0a) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 0 solid #000000;
}
.menu_dark_theme ul p, .menu_dark_theme ul ul, .menu_dark_theme ul li, .menu_dark_theme ul h2, .menu_dark_theme ul h3 {
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 60px;
}
.menu_dark_theme ul h2, .menu_dark_theme ul h3 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
}
.menu_dark_theme ul .imgshadow_dark, .menu_dark_theme ul .imgshadow_light {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;
}
.menu_dark_theme ul .imgshadow_light {
    border: 1px solid #777777;
}
.menu_dark_theme ul li .black_box, .menu_dark_theme ul li .dark_grey_box {
    background-color: #0a0a0a;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #000000 inset;
}
.menu_dark_theme ul li .greybox li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0a0a0a;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.menu_dark_theme ul li .greybox li:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #141414;
    border: 1px solid #111111;
}
.menu_dark_theme ul li .plus li {
    background: url("plus_dark.png") no-repeat scroll left 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.menu_dark_theme ul .levels a.parent, .menu_dark_theme ul .levels a.parent:hover {
    background: url("arrow_right2.png") no-repeat scroll right center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.menu_dark_theme ul .contact_form input:focus, .menu_dark_theme ul .contact_form textarea:focus, .menu_dark_theme ul .contact_form select:focus {
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.menu_dark_theme ul .contact_form input:hover, .menu_dark_theme ul .contact_form textarea:hover, .menu_dark_theme ul .contact_form select:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.menu_dark_theme ul .contact_form input, .menu_dark_theme ul .contact_form textarea, .menu_dark_theme ul .contact_form select {
    background-color: #555555;
    border: 1px solid #0a0a0a;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.menu_dark_theme ul .contact_form input.button {
    background-color: #999999;
    border: 1px solid #0a0a0a;
    color: #222222;
}
.menu_dark_theme ul .contact_form input.button:hover {
    background-color: #222222;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    color: #eeeeee;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu li:hover div a {
    border-bottom: medium none;
}
.menu_black {
}
.wrapper_menu .menu_black {
}
.wrapper_menu_full .menu_black {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_black li:hover div a {
    color: #ccc;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_black li:hover div a:hover {
    color: #eee;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_black li ul li a:hover {
    color: #eee;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_black li:hover div a {
    color: #444;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_black li:hover div a:hover {
    color: #777;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_black li ul li a:hover {
    color: #777;
}
.menu_blue {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #0272a7, #013953) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.wrapper_menu .menu_blue {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    border-color: #029feb #015b86 #015b86;
    border-image: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #015b86;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
.wrapper_menu_full .menu_blue {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #015b86;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_blue li:hover div a {
    color: #0294da;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_blue li:hover div a:hover {
    color: #33bcfd;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_blue li ul li a:hover {
    color: #33bcfd;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_blue li:hover div a {
    color: #015b86;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_blue li:hover div a:hover {
    color: #029feb;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_blue li ul li a:hover {
    color: #029feb;
}
.menu_brown {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #736033, #382f19) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.wrapper_menu .menu_brown {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    border-color: #a28748 #5c4c29 #5c4c29;
    border-image: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #5c4c29;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
.wrapper_menu_full .menu_brown {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #5c4c29;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_brown li:hover div a {
    color: #8b733e;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_brown li:hover div a:hover {
    color: #bfa670;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_brown li ul li a:hover {
    color: #bfa670;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_brown li:hover div a {
    color: #5c4c29;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_brown li:hover div a:hover {
    color: #a28748;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_brown li ul li a:hover {
    color: #a28748;
}
.menu_green {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #658c26, #354914) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.wrapper_menu .menu_green {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    border-color: #8bc135 #52711f #52711f;
    border-image: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #52711f;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
.wrapper_menu_full .menu_green {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #52711f;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_green li:hover div a {
    color: #6f992a;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_green li:hover div a:hover {
    color: #a3d158;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_green li ul li a:hover {
    color: #a3d158;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_green li:hover div a {
    color: #52711f;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_green li:hover div a:hover {
    color: #8bc135;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_green li ul li a:hover {
    color: #8bc135;
}
.menu_lightblue {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #709e8e, #52786b) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.wrapper_menu .menu_lightblue {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    border-color: #99b9ae #608c7d #608c7d;
    border-image: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #608c7d;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
.wrapper_menu_full .menu_lightblue {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #608c7d;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_lightblue li:hover div a {
    color: #608c7d;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_lightblue li:hover div a:hover {
    color: #99b9ae;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_lightblue li ul li a:hover {
    color: #99b9ae;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_lightblue li:hover div a {
    color: #608c7d;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_lightblue li:hover div a:hover {
    color: #99b9ae;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_lightblue li ul li a:hover {
    color: #99b9ae;
}
.menu_orange {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #ff6717, #c14300) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.wrapper_menu .menu_orange {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    border-color: #ff945b #f45500 #f45500;
    border-image: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #f45500;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
.wrapper_menu_full .menu_orange {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f45500;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_orange li:hover div a {
    color: #f45500;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_orange li:hover div a:hover {
    color: #ff945b;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_orange li ul li a:hover {
    color: #ff945b;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_orange li:hover div a {
    color: #f45500;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_orange li:hover div a:hover {
    color: #ff945b;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_orange li ul li a:hover {
    color: #ff945b;
}
.menu_pink {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #d50066, #80003d) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.wrapper_menu .menu_pink {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    border-color: #ff1a87 #b30055 #b30055;
    border-image: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #b30055;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
.wrapper_menu_full .menu_pink {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b30055;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_pink li:hover div a {
    color: #e6006d;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_pink li:hover div a:hover {
    color: #ff4da1;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_pink li ul li a:hover {
    color: #ff4da1;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_pink li:hover div a {
    color: #b30055;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_pink li:hover div a:hover {
    color: #ff1a87;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_pink li ul li a:hover {
    color: #ff1a87;
}
.menu_purple {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #8c8094, #615867) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.wrapper_menu .menu_purple {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    border-color: #ada5b3 #7b6f83 #7b6f83;
    border-image: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #7b6f83;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
.wrapper_menu_full .menu_purple {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #7b6f83;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_purple li:hover div a {
    color: #7b6f83;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_purple li:hover div a:hover {
    color: #ada5b3;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_purple li ul li a:hover {
    color: #ada5b3;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_purple li:hover div a {
    color: #7b6f83;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_purple li:hover div a:hover {
    color: #ada5b3;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_purple li ul li a:hover {
    color: #ada5b3;
}
.menu_red {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #d70b02, #830701) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.wrapper_menu .menu_red {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    border-color: #fd190f #a40802 #a40802;
    border-image: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #a40802;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
.wrapper_menu_full .menu_red {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a40802;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_red li:hover div a {
    color: #d60a03;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_red li:hover div a:hover {
    color: #fd5953;
}
.menu_dark_theme .menu_red li ul li a:hover {
    color: #fd5953;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_red li:hover div a {
    color: #a40802;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_red li:hover div a:hover {
    color: #fd190f;
}
.menu_light_theme .menu_red li ul li a:hover {
    color: #fd190f;
}
.menu li.noactive, .menu li.noactive:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: medium none;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.menu li.noactive a {
    border-bottom: medium none;
    padding: 5px 27px 3px 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
.menu li.noactive.right {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```